# Make barchart jqplot-point-label clickable primefaces

Tags: jquery, primefaces, bar-chart, jquery-events, jqplot

I am using PrimeFaces library to create BarChart but I am facing following issue. I have some very high values in my barchart and some very low. I have a click action on my bar which opens a dialog, but for smaller values like 4,30 below, I am unable to perform this action. Is there a way by which I can click the numbers and create a dialog in prime faces? Following is the code of my barchart:

```
<div id="chartrow" class="ui-grid-row">
 <p:chart id="usageChart" style="height: 550px" type="bar" model="#
 {usagemanager.barModel}">
 <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{usagemanager.itemSelect}" 
    oncomplete="PF('outputDialog').show()" update=":usageForm:dialog"/>
 </p:chart>
</div>
```

I have the following method as extender in my Javascript :

```
function barChartExtender() {        
                 // this = chart widget instance        
                 // this.cfg = options      
                this.cfg.seriesDefaults.rendererOptions.varyBarColor = true;
                this.cfg.grid = {
                    background: 'white',
                    drawGridLines: true
                };
                this.cfg.highlighter={
                    show: true,
                    tooltipAxes: 'y',
                    useAxesFormatters: false,
                    tooltipFormatString: "%d"
                };
            }
```

Knowing that the class of  label on  the bar in bar-chart is jqplot-point-label I was able to generate a click event using jQuery:

```
$=jQuery;
$(document).on('click',".jqplot-point-label",function() {
alert("456");
});
```

Now I need to call the JSF ajax event on this to get my work done. So is there a way or pointers to do that?

[image: Image of the bar chart]

Comment: Your question is effectively "How do I call a server side method from javascript". Search Stackoverflow for that. Hint: Use a PrimeFaces `p:remoteCommand`

Comment: Well it's not as straight forward, in my case , I guess my question becomes can i trigger the above itemSelect event using jquery.

Comment: I thought you fixed that part by stating "I was able to generate a click event using jquery. "